# Is there a better/elegant way of setting array keys to related values?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say, I've got an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => green
    [2] => blue
)
```

I want the keys of this array to be the same as the related values. So the result should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [red] => red
    [green] => green
    [blue] => blue
)
```

The values of the initial array will be unique, so this is not an issue.

To get the result, I would normally use a foreach loop:

```
$aResult = array();
foreach($aColors as $sValue)
{
  $aResult[$sValue] = $sValue;
}
```

My the question is: Is there a better/elegant way of doing this ?

**Edit:**
Many of you want to know why I need an array like this. So I'll explain. I'm using a framework, which generates a select box for me. The function uses array keys and values to apply them to the select options like so:

```
<select>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
```

In this case the keys would match the values.

Comment: Looks pretty "elegant" to me, last step would be unsetting the original keys that you might not want.

Comment: @DavidChen isn't that covered by the `$aResult = array()` declaration?

Comment: oops, didn't notice that :) thanks

Comment: ah, looks nice, but wouldn't a better pair such as "red"=>"Red" be better?

Comment: @DavidChen Yep, if we speak about colors, you are right, but this was only an example. In some cases it sometimes makes sense using keys and values which are the same. Think of clothing sizes (XS, S, M, L and so on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$aResult = array_combine($aColours, $aColours);
```

But its pretty pointless to do so because it doesn't give you anything that your original array doesn't already give you.

**EDIT**

You may also find the following variants useful:

```
$aColours = array('red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet');

$aResult = array_combine(
    $aColours,
    array_map(
        'ucfirst',
        $aColours
    )
);

var_dump($aResult);
```

uses the lower-case values defined in your initial array for the keys, but generates upper-case first letter for the display values

```
$aColours = array('Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Blue','Indigo','Violet');

$aResult = array_combine(
    array_map(
        'strtolower',
        $aColours
    ),
    $aColours
);

var_dump($aResult);
```

Uses mixed-case display values defined in your initial array for the values, but generates lower-case for the keys

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

The question remains why you would want it, but this is the way to do it.

Comment: Totally agree, if you have the value of ["key"], then wouldn't value of key be useless to you?

Comment: Perhaps it is some translation table.

Comment: @DavidChen I edited my question and explained why I need an array like this one